# How to keep user use different version with the same UWP APP?

Tags: deployment, uwp, windows-10

I have created UWP app packages with many versions and install the app by side-loading. If user A install the APP with version 1.0.0.0 and user B install it with version 1.0.0.1 on the same tablet, while user A logon the tablet, the APP will auto upgrade to 1.0.0.1.

I don't know why user A's APP has been upgraded. Can you share me some official document, I tried to google it but failed.

My another question is how to make user A keep the APP version without change?

Comment: like this behavior is not consistent between Win10 & Win8. On Win 8, different users can installed different versions of the same app on the same device, this is known as per-user installation.

Comment: I have consulted relative team,  this is feature is bydesign. Could you tell why do you want install different version app to each user account ?

Comment: The tablet share to different users to use, user A belongs to project 1, user B belongs to project 2, project 1 use the version 1.0.0.0, project 2 use the version 1.0.0.1.

Comment: @Nico,  Can you share me some official document or any linkage which mention this feature is bydesign.

Comment: I have tested in our PC with the 17134 OS version, I can not reproduce your issue. I can have the different users install different versions of the same app. By the way, your version number is very strange, because for Windows 10 packages, the last (fourth) section of the version number is reserved for Store use and must be left as 0 when you build your package (although the Store may change the value in this section). Besides, what is your OS version?

Comment: @Amy My OS build version is 15063. I manually changed the version in the Package.appxmanifest and open it with XML editor.

Comment: Still valid "issue" on OS version 18362. To reproduce: have two accounts, and side-load same version of UWP app per account. Then upgrade app on one of the accounts. The app on other account is also updated. Apparently this is "this is feature is bydesign" as @NicoZhu-MSFT stated.

Comment: @noxo from my testing, if the user installed an older version won't replace other account's app. I'm test it on 1703

Comment: @jerry yeah, older version does not replace newer version on other accounts. what i've randomly seen, is that, if you try to install older version, and other account has newer version, you'll get popup indicating that new version exists, and that will be installed instead.